# Как считать данные с COM порта и передать на node.js сервер?

Tags: node.js, сервер, serial, embedded

Возникла задача передать данные с COM порта на локальный сервер.
Написал такой код:

```
let http = require('http');
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const ReadLine = require("@serialport/parser-readline");

const port = new SerialPort("COM8", {
    baudRate: 9600,
});

const parser = new ReadLine();
port.pipe(parser);

port.on('readable', function () {
    console.log('Data:', port.read());
});


let server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log('URL страницы: ' + req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello, World!');
    
});

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Мы отслеживаем порт 3000');
```

У меня получается открыть COM порт и начать забирать оттуда данные. Эти данные выводятся в консоли терминала.
Вопрос в том, как эти данные вывести на страницу локального сервера?

Comment: не понятная задача. получили данные с кома, отправили на сервер. отправили сырыми? зачем они серверу? что дальше происходит с данными?

Comment: так-то всё просто: локально организовали очередь (для того чтобы последовательно передавать поступающие данные на сервер. используем p-queue с конкуренцией = 1), получили данные с порта, через очередь кинули на сервер POST-запрос, на сервере пульнули в обработчик или коллекцию. или рядом с "сервером" подняли веб-сокет сервер и кидаем данные в него, а он как-то передаёт в сервер

Comment: в общем, задача недостаточна определена, чтобы дать какое-то одно решение - сплошные фантазии

Comment: Суля по тому, что я понял, вам нужно закэшировать их где-то, потом уже выводить, Либо это должен быть обработчик события, который обновляет страницу (или её часть, мы же в web 2.0!) по приходу новых данных.